# Using "gets" for String input in C

Tags: c, fgets, gets

I have been trying to get a string input from a user using `fgets`
but fgets does not wait for input so upon investagation I learned of the `gets` function which seems to be working fine. My questions are: 1. Why does `gets` work when I input more than 10 characters if I declared an array of only ten elements. Here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){

    char name[10];

    printf("Please enter your name: ");
    gets(name);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%s", name);

    return 0;

}
```

my input when testing: morethantenletters 
will output: 'morethantenletters' 
Surely, this should have caused some errors, no? Since `name` is only ten elements long.

2. My next question is that my code also works when I use `gets(&name)` instead of `gets(name)`-- I do not understand why. The `&name` is sending the address of `name`.
while `name` is just sending the value of it, no?

Comment: Never use gets().  It provides no protection against memory overflow.

Comment: `fgets` does wait for input.

Comment: The blocking isn't the issue; both fgets() and gets() block appropriately for input.  The trouble is gets() has no way to know how much space is available in the target char*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is exactly why you should always use `fgets` to replace `gets`. The array `name` has only 10 elements, but you are trying to store in it more than it's capable of. `fgets` prevents the program from buffer overflow, but `gets` doesn't.

It's undefined behavior when you are using `gets` in this way, don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

```
Since name is only ten elements long.
```

Anything accepted more than `10` will be buffer overrun and may cause run time issues. So make sure your size is right. hint: Use `getline` or `fgets` instead.

```
while name is just sending the value of it, no?
```

For char arrays, `name` is also address to its starting position.

Comment: Use fgets() instead because the max size is specified.  Don't use gets()!.  The man pages clearly say this.