# Why, in C code, would a gets and puts behave differently when nothing is changed but the letters going into it?

Tags: c, bash, gdb, gets, puts

Hey guys (and girls),
                        I have tried and tried to understand this. I have even stepped through with gdb and cannot understand it. So, I'm going to have to bother one of you guys. I have a simple menu where each choice is an integer, 1 through 12, monotonically increasing like normal. Well, I'm trying to code it so that if you select, say, five (5) it begins at there and continues to iterate through by asking name, age, ect. This is for an assignment so please don't tell me how to do that. All I need to know is for choice number 1 I am using an if statement and that if statement begins with these lines...

```
    printf("Enter Name: \n");
    gets(name);
    printf("Name: ");
    puts(name);
    printf("\n");
```

This code works exactly as intended. Then, later in the statement, after doing a few of the same type of thing, except using scanf for a float in the block just before. I have this code...

```
    printf("Enter Major: \n");
    gets(major);
    printf("Major: ");
    printf("\n");
```

This code will not wait on any input. It just prints out Major: then Major: again on the next line. I can't understand it. I stepped through with gdb and it worked properly when stepping. Then, when I run it the same thing happens again. Would someone please let me know what is going on? Thanks a lot, in advance, for the help. I know the vast majority of the people on here are professionals and don't care to be bugged with things so simple but I just cannot find the answer and my professor has left for the day. THanks guys. -court

Perhaps I should give you guys the code just before the problematic code. It is this, which works as intended...
        printf("Enter Height: \n");
        scanf("%f", &height);
        printf("Height: %f2.1.", height);
The variables involved are declared as... char name[25], major[25]; and float height. Thanks again.

Comment: Never use `gets()`.  **Never** use `gets()`.  It is impossible to use securely.

Comment: [Never use `gets()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21085028/10077).

Comment: And don't use `scanf()` either, its behavior is strange and inconsistent, especially with regards to whitespace. Use `fgets()` and `strtod()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> except using scanf for a float in the block just before

is the key to your problem. If you do `scanf("%f", &var)`, and enter a number terminated with a line feed, scanf will NOT read the line feed. Try entering "123abcd" for your float and you'll see the abcd will get stuffed into major.

Use `scanf("%f ", &var)` to skip over any potential whitespace behind your number (note the blank in the format string).

Besides, you shouldn't use gets, as it may cause buffer overflows, but if you're just starting to learn, this probably isn't your main problem right now.

Comment: Yes sir(s). But, I will not be able to write my code without scanf. What do I use instead?

Comment: If, for some reason, you can't use H2CO3's `fgets/strtod` combination, use `"%f "` as your format string, just as i said.

Comment: Yes Sir, it did add that string. I thought gets and puts was more efficient than scanf. That's why I used it. It's a system engineering class. But, I won't any more. So, I use scanf to hold strings?

Comment: I see, I see it now. Thank you guys a TON! And, sorry to bother you.

Comment: @court Don't worry about "efficiency". Why bother? Until you are a beginner, and you can't even write a **correct** program, it's just **wrong** to worry about speed. Don't do that. Even later on, you will only want to optimize when you run into an actual performance issue. And then you *still* don't want to try to second guess the compiler/OS/C library. Only optimize after having profiled/benchmarked your code.

Comment: It's ok for you to use gets *now*. Basically, as you're just learning at the moment, if you're at lesson 3 now, you'll learn what a buffer is in lesson 13, why it can overflow and why that should be avoided in lesson 17, and how to write programs securely in lesson 25. So keep using gets for now, if you promise to stop using it once you've reached lesson 17.

Comment: I understand. I won't worry about it any more then. I was just wanting to do well in the class. But, I understand completely what you mean.

Comment: I promise. I'm just going to switch to fgets. But, really quickly, what does f stand for?

Comment: The `f` stands for file, as `fgets` will allow you to read from files as well as your terminal. But the key point is, fgets allows you to specify the size of your string. If you define `char name[10]` and enter more than 10 characters to gets, it will happily overwrite memory somewhere else in your program. If, instead, you call `fgets(name, 10, stdin)`, `fgets` will make sure not to read more than 10 characters. Simply speaking, `stdin` is the special file that is normally connected to your terminal.

Comment: I see, it's dangerous for low level reasons I don't understand yet.  Thank you very much for your help.